# Why we need to use Context.obtainStyledAttributes and declare-styleable to obtain attribute of a GUI component

Tags: java, android

I just came across some tutorial code example which are using `declare-styleable` in XML and `Context.obtainStyledAttributes` in Java code.

My understanding is, *it is trying to obtain the attribute (Like background color) of a GUI component.*

**I was wondering, why do we need to go through these cumbersome steps just to obtain a simple attribute? If I want to retrieve a GUI component attributes each time, I have to create a new XML file, and add in the attribute I want to retrieve to the XML file itself. Can we have something simpler?**

Currently, here is what I need to do when I try to obtain attribute of a GUI component.

---

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html

Create an XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="HelloGallery">
        <attr name="android:galleryItemBackground" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Have the following Java code.

```
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.HelloGallery);
mGalleryItemBackground = a.getResourceId(
        R.styleable.HelloGallery_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
a.recycle();
```

---

Can we have something simple like

```
helloGalleryInstance.getBackground();
```

As in Swing, here is what I usually do to obtain an attribute of a GUI component. It is fun and easy. Can we have something similar in Android?

```
instaceOfAComponent.getBackground();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, there is a lot more to it than that.  The technique of using styles and getting the attributes is a way to allow consumers of the custom component to use XML attributes that you define for the control.  For example, you might create a TitleWithSubtitle control that has a subtitle text size attribute.  This technique would let you get the value from the layout XML.  You could still add a getSubtitleTextSize() method to the control itself, but this would serve a different purpose.

Answer (score 0):

To get the background of a `View`, call `getBackground()`.

Comment: Do you know why in Android hello-gallery tutorial, instead of passing in Context into ImageAdapter constructor, and use obtainStyledAttributes method to retrieve Gallery's background, why don't they just pass in an instance of Gallery into the constructor, and invoke gallery.getBackground()?

Comment: @Yan Cheng CHEOK: In this case, they're not asking for the Gallery's background. They are defining a background for the items within the Gallery. There's a difference. That being said, I find this particular sample to be poorly written.